# Write f(x) as a piecewise function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

How to write $f(x)=||3x+1|-7|$ as a piecewise function?

I am confused by the absolute value within an absolute value.

I was able to set $|3x+1|-7=0$ to determine that the x-intercepts of $f(x)$ are $2$ and $-8/3$.

What can I do next?

Comment: $|\text{stuff}|=\begin{cases}\text{stuff}&\text{stuff}\geq0\\-1\cdot\text{stuff} & \text{stuff}<0\end{cases}$

Comment: The absolute value is like an "if" statement, right? "If $|3x+1|-7<0$, then $f(x)=-(|3x+1|-7)$, otherwise $f(x)=+(|3x+1|-y)$. Now, for each one of these cases, you can think of two sub-cases: if $3x+1<0$ or if $3x+1\geq0$. You do the algebra and express $f(x)$ in 4 pieces, 2 for every sub-case of the 2 cases.

Answer (score 1):

To have a piecewise function, you want "cases".
The cases are the specific $x$-values so that the function "changes".
Note that by definition,
$$
|a|=\begin{cases}
a, \qquad \text{if} \ a\geq 0, \\ -a, \quad \text{if} \ a < 0.
\end{cases}
$$
So focus in on your absolute value $||3x+1| - 7|$.
Work with the inside first: $|3x+1|$.
The cases are when $x\geq -\frac{1}{3}$ and $x< -\frac{1}{3}$ (what does the expression look like in each case?).

Now work with the outside absolute value $||3x+1|-7|$.
You have to simplify the inside first into the two cases found above, and then you can simplify the entire thing in a similar procedure.